# estimating derivative of a random function at a point

Tags: nonparametric, density-function

I have a random function $f_n(x):R\to R$. At each point $x\in R$, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ at $1/\sqrt{n}$ rate. While $f(x)$ is smooth, the functions $f_n(x)$ for fixed $n$ are more like step functions, becoming smoother with $n$ growing. Are there methods (even naive methods, and maybe imposing some conditions on $f$) for computing the derivative at a point $x_0\in R$?

I know about density estimation, the case when $f_n$ are CDFs, but $f$ is an arbitrary smooth function. But this is easier than density estimation, because I'm just asking about a single point.

Comment: Evidently you have a *sequence* of functions.  In what sense are these functions "random"?  Please tell us the model you have in mind and how you know the $f_n.$  (It sounds like you might be estimating them from data.  What kind of data and how are you making the estimates?)